# draftwatermark picks up italics from the top of the next page and produces Postscript, and no large smallcaps italics fonts are available in fix-cm

Tags: amsthm, font-encodings, italic, dvi-mode, draftwatermark

Feeding `latex` with

```latex
\RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[text={\textsc{Confidential \ Draft}}, angle=53.2, fontsize={92.4pt}]{draftwatermark}% in a nonminimal book, we use color={[gray]{0.95}} and slightly different angle and fontsize.
\newtheorem*{thm}{Theorem}
\begin{document}
\vspace*{122ex}% with \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
%\vspace*{121.74ex}% without \RequirePackage{fix-cm}
\begin{thm}
  This text in italics makes the first watermark italics or too small.
\end{thm}

The second watermark is how it's intended to be when \texttt{fix-cm} and \texttt{pdflatex} are used.
\end{document}
```

prints (with other stuff)

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/scit' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/scsl' instead on input line 12.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/scsl' in size <92.4> not available
(Font)              size <35.83> substituted on input line 12.

[1] [2] (./mwe.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 56.56999pt have occurred.
```

to the console.

Viewing the result with `xdvi` yields

`xdvi-xaw: Warning: Raw Postscript commands on page 2 may be rendered incorrectly.`

on the console, whereas the documentation of draftwatermark clearly states quite the opposite, “There is no use of Postscript specials or other driver-dependent tricks […]”.  We observe (cutting to the contents)

[image: first page with xdvi]

on the first page and

[image: second page with xdvi]

on the second page.

As you see, both watermarks are drawn straight, i.e., not tilted at any nonzero angle. Further, the first watermark is italics, whereas it should be upright. Finally, the first watermark is smaller than its font size suggests it should be.

All this is bad but not very bad because we use the DVI output mostly for debugging rather than for the final output.

When compiling the same code with `pdflatex` and viewing the result with evince, the PostScript issue disappears and the two others remain. The compilation prints

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/scit' undefined
(Font)              using `T1/cmr/m/scsl' instead on input line 12.


LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T1/cmr/m/scsl' in size <92.4> not available
(Font)              size <35.83> substituted on input line 12.

[1{/var/lib/texmf/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap/pdftex.map}{/usr/share/texmf/fonts/en
c/dvips/cm-super/cm-super-t1.enc}] [2] (./mwe.aux)

LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 56.56999pt have occurred.
```

to the console. The contents of first page of the resulting PDF file is

[image: first page with evince]

whereas the second page is, finally as expected,

[image: second page viewed with evince]

To see how fix-cm is involved, remove `\RequirePackage{fix-cm}` and introduce the vskip of 121.74ex instead of 122ex.

Why does all this happen, who are the culprits, and what to do? I'd be very grateful for bug fixes for the three issues. The second issue is the most pressing for us: draftwatermark should not pick up the current text style (here: italics) for the watermark from some (not all!) text on the first line of the next page.

Comment: use \normalfont in the watermark: `text={\normalfont\textsc{Confidential \ Draft}}`.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Thank you! This workaround does the job for me for the second and third issues.

Comment: clearly you can not have rotated text in the xdvi targetted dvi without postscript specials so your first issue is expected and unavoidable.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does this mean that the DVI format itself doesn't support rotated/tilted text?

Comment: @AlMa0 yes, you need `\special` and xdvi has no native support for rotation either so you rely on its limited support for simple postscript in `\special` that are targeted for dvips. So sometimes it works, sometimes it doesn't, it depends on exactly what postscript is inserted, and whether xdvi can, possibly with the help of ghostscript in the background, so something with it.

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple issues here, some of them certainly not related to draftwatermark.

1. First issue is that while in draftwatermark itself there is no use of Postscript specials or other driver-dependent tricks, in order to produce rotated text it uses a standard LaTeX package (graphicx) to do so. Unfortunately, xdvi is often incapable to deal with what graphicx tries to do. Some opened bug reports about this (e.g., see https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=53971). However no one really felt any urgency to deal with them, probably because there are TeX engines which do away with the dvi format. This is the reason why you do not get rotated text in xdvi. If you go through dvips you will get it, though. I would suggest doing away with postscript too by using pdflatex or lualatex, though.
2. Second issue is that draftwatermark picks whatever font is selected at the time the LaTeX shipout/background hook is invoked to put a background on a page. Because this may not be what is desired, it is better to include full font selection commands inside the watermark text (e.g., \normalfont).

Comment: graphicx could (and originally did) have a xdvi specific backend but xdvi doesn't natively support rotation anyway so any xdvi specific option would just give a message that rotation is not supported. By using the dvips back end you get postscript specials which xdvi can understand in some simple cases, and you get a dvi you can print via dvips rather than one that is only usable with xdvi. So graphicx generating postscript specials is by choice not because of lack of urgency.

Comment: Thank you!!! I guess, the third issue (the absence of large fonts) is also an issue for some font family. Cm-super?